# Sequelize: Increment and updated_at in same method

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Using Sequelize is there a way to increment a value and also update the `updated_at` column in the same call? I would assume there is a way to do this as using the increment method is updating the table so the `updated_at` column should be updated at the same time, without having to waste a second call only to update the `updated_at` column.

```
    await account.increment(
        ["balance"],
        {
          by: updateAmount,
        },
        { transaction: transaction }
      );

      await account.update(
        {
          updated_at: new Date()
        },
        { transaction: transaction }
      );
```

The [docs](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#increment-decrement) dont seem to mention it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. As the docs say `increment` is a convenience method. If you need to do more then incrementing then you have to use the `update` method.

Comment: Thats a pity, is there a way to increment using the update method?